# Move position in post list for a custom checkbox column

Tags: posts, widgets, query-posts

I have made checkboxes to every post in post list.

**Question:**
How can I change the the position for the new column.
Now it`s at the right side of the post list. After "Date".
How can I move it example before the title column ?

The files for the plugin is here, if you would take a look.
https://github.com/bjovaar/terplugin

[image: Admin post list]

Comment: can you ask 1 question per question? This isn't a discussion forum so you need to ask a single question, asking multiple questions can severely limit the number of people who can respond as they now have to answer all the questions and get all of them correct. Also, use code blocks instead of screenshots of code, otherwise people trying to answer have to type out what you've put to work with the code

Answer (score 0):

[`manage_posts_columns`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_posts_columns/) is a filter that you can use to change the order of the columns.
It takes two parameters - list of columns and type of the post (for which the table is displayed).
If the post type is `post` change the order of the array elements keeping the keys and values.

The column name is set as the CSS class in the table cell, like

```
<td class="recommendations column-recommendations"`
```

Sample solution:

```
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'wpse403447_reorder_cols', 100, 2 );

function wpse403447_reorder_cols( $columns, $post_type )
{
    //
    // column to move
    $moved_col_key = '{name-of-the-recommendation-column}';
    $moved_col_title = '';

    if ( $post_type != 'post' || !isset( $columns[$moved_col_key] ) )
        return $columns;

    //
    // "title" column
    $title_col = 'title';
    $reordered = [];
    foreach( $columns as $col => $title ) {
        if ( $col == $moved_col_key ) {
            $moved_col_title = $title;
            continue;
        }
        if ( $col == $title_col )
            $reordered[ $moved_col_key ] = '';
            
        $reordered[ $col ] = $title;
    }
    $reordered[ $moved_col_key ] = $moved_col_title;
    
    return $reordered;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from https://www.isitwp.com/change-wordpress-admin-post-columns-order/

All you have to do is add this code to your theme’s functions.php file or in a site-specific plugin:

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'column_order');
function column_order($columns) {
  $n_columns = array();
  $move = 'author'; // what to move
  $before = 'title'; // move before this
  foreach($columns as $key => $value) {
    if ($key==$before){
      $n_columns[$move] = $move;
    }
      $n_columns[$key] = $value;
  }
  return $n_columns;
}
```

If you want to move multiple columns you will need to do things in another way as the above code was just to make things as simple as possible. The next snippet will move both the date and author columns before the post title column.

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'column_order');
function column_order($columns) {
  $n_columns = array();
  $before = 'title'; // move before this
 
  foreach($columns as $key => $value) {
    if ($key==$before){
      $n_columns['date'] = '';
      $n_columns['author'] = '';
    }
      $n_columns[$key] = $value;
  }
  return $n_columns;
}
```